# Trying to get 1st ip address from a json file using jq to get expected output

Tags: arrays, json, shell, jq

Below is the output I am trying to get from a json file. Can someone please help to get the expected output with line of code?

Note : JSON file can't be changed and I don't want to get the 2nd ip address in the output.
shell/bash/awk/sed programs preferable.

***JSON :***

`{"result":[{"description": "Validate application after update for expected operation\nVM Name: fldcldswps7175 \nManaged Instance ID: i-01a2asda390b99 \nIP Address: 10.199.157.67,10.199.157.68","status":true}, {"name":"XML", "good":false}]}`

***Output :***
10.199.157.67

***Tried Code :***
`IPaddress=('.result'|grep "description"|grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'|sed 's/,*$//g'|tr -d ',')  echo $IPaddress`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried code as your efforts in your question, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts now. Please do let us know if you can use commands like `jq` OR python's modules? Since experts always advice to use those tools who understand json well. If you don't have these and can't install them then we can look for other shell/bash/awk/perl/sed programs, kindly confirm once.

Comment: shell/bash/awk/sed programs preferable.

Comment: Ok thanks for information. I have edited your question now. Looks pretty much Good. One more question: Check your latest question(because I updated it), those `\n` are literal characters in json? OR they need to be changed to new lines here in your input? Because that will change the code then, please confirm once.

Comment: OR your json file is single line one? Like you tried to post before.

Comment: \n are literal characters in json.

Comment: Actually that's the file format. But if we try to format through json formatter then it will look like the one you updated.

Answer (score 3):

As `jq` is tagged, here's a solution using `jq`. It traverses in the JSON file to the value in `.result[0].description`, selects the last `[-1]` text line, applies the regex, and outputs the first `[0]` result.

```bash
jq --arg regex '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' -r '
  .result[0].description | split("\n")[-1] | [scan($regex)][0]
' file.json
```

```json
10.199.157.67
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/A4YlvyU8RQL)

Comment: I am getting output as null.

Comment: @SayantanJana For the solution, I had to come up with some constraints (last line, first match), which may not hold for your actual input data. Please elaborate on your sample data and/or try playing with the provided demo by iteratively transforming the sample data to your actual one.

Comment: Let me explain you some details more. I am trying to fetch some data through api. Storing those details in $ctasks. So now I am trying to get selected details from the fetched data. So below line of code will work? IPAddress=( $(echo "$ctasks"|jq --arg regex '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' -r ' .result[0].description | split("\n")[-1] | [scan($regex)][0]') )

Comment: @SayantanJana `echo` is often a problematic choice. If you are using Bash, try `IPAddress="$(jq --arg … <<< "$ctasks")"`. Does `jq --arg … <<< "$ctasks"` work on its own (without the variable assignment)?

Comment: Still getting null as output. Anyway will try to find out more on this. Thank You for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following GNU `grep` command. Since OP mentioned external tools libraries can't be used for OP's system so using `grep` code here, though its always advised to use json aware tools itself.

```
grep -oP '^\{"result":\[.*IP Address: \K[^,]*' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using GNU `grep`'s `-oP` options here, which will print matched data and enable PCRE regex flavor respectively. In main program using regex `^\{"result":\[.*IP Address: \K[^,]*` where it will match values from starting `{"result":` to till string `IP Address:` then I am using `\K` option which will allow match to happen but will make sure its value is getting washed out so that values coming after `\K` only are getting printed. Then using `[^,]*` will catch ip address value everything just before 1st comma occurrence.

***NOTE:*** This considers that your json is of one line like mentioned in comments.

Comment: @SayantanJana, since you don't have latest `awk` and `grep` so please try like: `wk -v RS= 'match($0,/^{\n\s+"result":\s+\[{\n\s+"description":\s.*?\\nIP Address:\s/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'` on your variable once and let me know what it gives?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `capture`:

```
.result[0].description | capture("Address: *(?<address>[0-9.]*)").address
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to make it more complicated than necessary :

> ```
> echo "${ _input_data_ }" | 
>
> mawk ++NF RS='^$' OFS= FS='.+IP Address: |,.*$'
> ```

```
10.199.157.67
```